How to Resolve "You are not allowed to make changes to budgets" Error in Google Ads API?
I'm trying to create an AccountBudgetProposal using the Google Ads API (v14), but I keep encountering the following error:
Request with ID "xxxx" failed with status "INVALID_ARGUMENT" and includes the following errors:
Error with message "You are not allowed to make changes to budgets."On field: operation
Steps I've taken:

Verified Permissions:

My account has "Standard" access level, which I believe should be sufficient.

Confirmed that I have appropriate permissions to make changes to budgets.



Checked Billing Setup Status:

Verified that the billing_setup_id is active and correctly formatted.

Used the following code to check the status of the billing setup:




from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient
from google.ads.googleads.errors import GoogleAdsException

def get_billing_setup_status(client, customer_id, billing_setup_id):
    ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService")

    query = f"""
        SELECT
            billing_setup.id,
            billing_setup.status
        FROM billing_setup
        WHERE billing_setup.resource_name = 'customers/{customer_id}/billingSetups/{billing_setup_id}'
    """

    try:
        response = ga_service.search(customer_id=customer_id, query=query)
        for row in response:
            billing_setup = row.billing_setup
            status = billing_setup.status
            status_name = client.enums.BillingSetupStatusEnum.BillingSetupStatus(status).name
            print(f"Billing setup ID: {billing_setup.id}, Status: {status_name}")
            return status_name
    except GoogleAdsException as ex:
        print(f'Request with ID "{ex.request_id}" failed with status "{ex.error.code().name}" and includes the following errors:')
        for error in ex.failure.errors:
            print(f'\tError with message "{error.message}".')
            if error.location:
                for field_path_element in error.location.field_path_elements:
                    print(f'\t\tOn field: {field_path_element.field_name}')
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    google_ads_client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage('path_to_google_ads.yaml', version='v14')
    customer_id = 'your_customer_id'  # Replace with your customer ID
    billing_setup_id = 'your_billing_setup_id'  # Replace with your billing setup ID

    billing_setup_status = get_billing_setup_status(google_ads_client, customer_id, billing_setup_id)
    if billing_setup_status == "ACTIVE":
        print(f"Billing setup {billing_setup_id} is active.")
    else:
        print(f"Billing setup {billing_setup_id} is not active or not found.")

Creating Account Budget Proposal:

Attempted to create the AccountBudgetProposal using the following code:
from google.ads.googleads.client import GoogleAdsClient
from google.ads.googleads.errors import GoogleAdsException

def create_account_budget_proposal(client, customer_id, billing_setup_id):
    account_budget_proposal_service = client.get_service("AccountBudgetProposalService")

    account_budget_proposal_operation = client.get_type("AccountBudgetProposalOperation")
    proposal = account_budget_proposal_operation.create

    proposal.proposal_type = client.enums.AccountBudgetProposalTypeEnum.CREATE
    proposal.billing_setup = f'customers/{customer_id}/billingSetups/{billing_setup_id}'
    proposal.proposed_name = "Account Budget Proposal (example)"
    proposal.proposed_start_time_type = client.enums.TimeTypeEnum.NOW
    proposal.proposed_end_time_type = client.enums.TimeTypeEnum.FOREVER
    proposal.proposed_spending_limit_micros = 100000000  # Example amount: $100,000.00

    try:
        account_budget_proposal_response = account_budget_proposal_service.mutate_account_budget_proposals(
            customer_id=customer_id,
            operations=[account_budget_proposal_operation],
        )
        print(f"Created account budget proposal '{account_budget_proposal_response.results[0].resource_name}'.")
    except GoogleAdsException as ex:
        print(f'Request with ID "{ex.request_id}" failed with status "{ex.error.code().name}" and includes the following errors:')
        for error in ex.failure.errors:
            print(f'\tError with message "{error.message}".')
            if error.location:
                for field_path_element in error.location.field_path_elements:
                    print(f'\t\tOn field: {field_path_element.field_name}')
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    google_ads_client = GoogleAdsClient.load_from_storage('path_to_google_ads.yaml', version='v14')
    customer_id = 'your_customer_id'  # Replace with your customer ID
    billing_setup_id = 'your_billing_setup_id'  # Replace with your billing setup ID

    billing_setup_status = get_billing_setup_status(google_ads_client, customer_id, billing_setup_id)
    if billing_setup_status == "ACTIVE":
        create_account_budget_proposal(google_ads_client, customer_id, billing_setup_id)
    else:
        print("The billing setup ID is not active or not found. Please check the billing setup ID and try again.")



Questions:

Are there any specific permissions required beyond "Standard" to make changes to budgets?

Is there any additional configuration needed for billing_setup_id to be accepted?

Could there be any other reason why I am encountering this error despite having the correct permissions and an active billing setup?


Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!


